# How to make custom URLs on LAN

Tags: hosts, url

i've been trying to find a solution to this for a long time... what i wish to do is create custom URLs on LAN against which users can easily access to some site without using the actual URL e.g.

if the user types : http:searchme in the browser then he/she will be redirected to http:google.com

similarly, http:checkmail in the browser and he/she will be landed on http:gmail.com

I read somewhere that such thing is possible by editing the Rhosts or hosts file on the server.

Any help here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

" create custom URLs on LAN " - just create a shared HTML page  with 2 links:
 searchme
 checkmail

Which are links to websites and PC on LAN can make it their home page. That would be simple way to do it.